# Add Video to Playlist after upload throws NotFound error (Youtube API v3)

Tags: c#, .net-core, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am using the .Net YouTube Api to upload a Video and add it to a Playlist. But adding a new PlaylistItem directly after a Video upload throws always a `Video not found [404]` error. Although the error is thrown, the video is added to the playlist. I also had same issue retrivig a Playlist after creating it. Using a Python Library I had none of this issues. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
// Upload Video
var newVideo = new Video
{
    Snippet = new VideoSnippet
    {
        Title = title,
        ...
    }
};

Video uploadedVideo = null;

void ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress progress)
{
    ...
}

void ResponseReceived(Video video)
{
    uploadedVideo = video;
}

await using var fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
var request = _youtubeService.Videos.Insert(newVideo, "snippet", fileStream, "video/*");
request.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
request.ResponseReceived += ResponseReceived;

await request.UploadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

// Add PlaylistItem
var newPlaylistItem = new PlaylistItem
{
    Snippet = new PlaylistItemSnippet
    {
        PlaylistId = playlistId,
        ResourceId = new ResourceId
        {
            Kind = "youtube#video",
            VideoId = uploadedVideo.Id
        }
    }
};

var playlistItem = await _youtubeService.PlaylistItems.Insert(newPlaylistItem, "snippet").ExecuteAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Most likely the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63872549

Comment: @yankee Thank you! Good to know I'm not the only one facing this issue.

Comment: Also the same problem was reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63938839/4092887